# Hibernate TypeResolver

Tags: java, hibernate, types, jodatime

I'm aware that hibernate recently redid its type system in 3.6.  I think this now allows you do associate a java Class with a Type (or UserType).  For example I use joda-time and have a couple of UserTypes that map the LocalDate and LocalDateTime into appropriate SQL types.

This works fine when working with objects but if I want to pass a joda type as a HQL parameter hibernate gets confused so I have to remember to supply the Type each time I make a call.

```
query.setParameter( "now", new LocalDateTime(), Hibernate.custom( LocalDateTimeType.class ) );
```

I think it is now possible during the Configuration/SessionFactory setup phase to say LocalDateTime -> LocalDatetimeType but I'm not sure how to do this.  I found the TypeResolver but had trouble deciphering which method I should be calling to achieve this.

Or please correct me if this is not possible even with the new type stuff in 3.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Simple enough when you know how.

```
configuration.getTypeResolver().registerTypeOverride( LocalDateTimeType.TYPE, new String[]{ LocalDateTime.class.getName() } );
configuration.getTypeResolver().registerTypeOverride( LocalDateType.TYPE, new String[]{ LocalDate.class.getName() } );
```

The TypeResolver lookups for unknown types use the class name so registering the full name of the class as the registrationKey does the job.