# java.util.Date.toString() is printing out wrong format

Tags: java, date, tostring

The following code prints out "vmtDataOrig.creationdate=2012-11-03"

```
VmtData vmtDataOrig = VmtDataDao.getInstance().loadVmt(1);
System.out.println("vmtDataOrig.creationdate=" + vmtDataOrig.getCreationDate().toString());
```

Here is the definition of the creationDate field in the VmtData class:

```
private Date creationDate = null;
```

Here is the hibernate mapping of the creationDate field to the database table column:

```
<property name="creationDate" column="CREATIONDATE" type="date"/>
```

The CREATIONDATE column in the MySQL database table is of type "date", and for the record retrieved it has the value "2012-11-03".

The Javadoc for the java.util.Date.toString() method says it is supposed to print the Date object in the form "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy".  Anyone know why it is printing it out in the form "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: Are you sure that's not `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: The VmtData.java has "import java.util.*;"  It does not import anything from java.sql

Comment: @pacoverflow It wouldn't be able to import `java.sql.Date` because of the collision (two separate `Date` classes imported).  This means that the Date returned in the method could be returning a `java.sql.Date`, but it would be explicitly typed in the method, like `java.sql.Date date = blah;`.

Comment: Always be specific when importing classes rather than using `import java.util.*;`. That way you are sure that you are not referring to classes from other packages.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533935/how-to-force-hibernate-to-return-dates-as-java-util-date-instead-of-timestamp) for a really horrendous way to force this conversion. However, if your database is only storing dates, you're not really going to be able to get *valid* data for, e.g. hours, minutes, seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the field is of type `java.util.Date`, Hibernate may well still be *populating* it with a `java.sql.Date`, which subclasses `java.util.Date` and overrides `toString()`... For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.util.Date date = new java.sql.Date(0);
        System.out.println(date); // 1970-01-01
    }
}
```

It's easy to check that though:

```
System.out.println(vmtDataOrig.getCreationDate().getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate type is date, hence the java.sql.Date is used (which is sub-class of java.util.date). If you change hibernate type to java.sql.Timestamp, it would use its toString() implementation.