# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Time]

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate

Can't get time field from input, constantly getting error message:

> Field error in object 'recipe' on field 'prepTime': rejected value
>   [04:00]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.recipe.prepTime,typeMismatch.prepTime,typeMismatch.java.sql.Time,typeMismatch];
>
> arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
>       codes [recipe.prepTime,prepTime]; arguments []; default message [prepTime]]; 
>       default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.sql.Time] for property
>   'prepTime'; 
>       nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
>       Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Time]
>   for value '04:00'; 
>      nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: 
>      No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type
>   [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Time]]

My POJO class:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] photo;

    @Size (min=3, max=100, message = "size of field Name must be between 3 and 100")
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "mm:ss")
    private Time prepTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "mm:ss")
    private Time cookTime;

    private String addedFlag;
```

and input field in form html:

```
<input type="time" th:placeholder="${recipe.prepTime}" th:field="${recipe.prepTime}"/>
```

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add @Temporal annotation.

Comment: Can't add that annotation to Time field

Comment: Annotation @Temporal can be added to DateTime or Date fields only, not Time

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533935/how-to-force-hibernate-to-return-dates-as-java-util-date-instead-of-timestamp

Comment: Try using hibernate converter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750026/java-8-localdatetime-and-hibernate-4

Comment: solved: changed type of field from Time to Date, added @Temporal annotation and it works