# JPA Query - no appropriate constructor in class error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, dto

I have an Employee entity class that has many columns. I want to get some columns from this class, therefore I have used dtos. I created a new BaseEmployee class and writed query in EmployeeRepository. But I get this error: "no appropriate constructor in class error" when I try to run app.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private  int id;
    @Column(name = "birth_date")   
    private Date birthDate;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private char gender;
    @Column(name = "hire_date")  
    private Date hireDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private List<Title> titles; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private List<Salary> salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<DeptEmp> departmentList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
   private List<DeptManager> managerDepartment;

}
```

My dto class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseEmployee {

    private  int id;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private char gender;
    private Date hireDate;

}
```

Jpa Repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
    
    List<Employee> getByFirstNameContains(String firstName);
    List<Employee> getByFirstNameStartsWith(String firstName);


    @Query("Select new dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee"
    + "(e.id, e.birthDate, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.gender, e.hireDate) From Employee e WHERE e.id = :id")
    Optional<BaseEmployee> getBaseEmployeeById(int id);
    
    
}
```

Errors:

```
HH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-02-20 16:33:42.533  INFO 24371 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-20 16:33:42.559  INFO 24371 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-20 16:33:43.431 ERROR 24371 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        :  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, char, java.util.Date
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee]
2022-02-20 16:33:43.443 ERROR 24371 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        :  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, char, java.util.Date
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee]

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.BaseEmployee]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, char, java.util.Date
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all-args constructor that Lombok generates calls for two arguments of type `java.util.Date`.

When hibernate executes your jpql, it uses `org.hibernate.type.TimestampType` objects in the constructor and not `java.util.Date` objects. Of course no such constuctor was generated, hence the error.

Here is a stack overflow discussion of how to deal with this situation: [How to force Hibernate to return dates as java.util.Date instead of Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533935/how-to-force-hibernate-to-return-dates-as-java-util-date-instead-of-timestamp)

Comment: I've used `java.sql.Date` in my Employee class and BaseEmployee. It's worked when I changed `java.sql.Date` to `java.util.Date` in BaseEmployee.  I just started learning spring web :)  I thought that java.sql.date would work both class. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite straightforward, your class `BaseEmployee` lacks the appropriate constructor needed to execute `getBaseEmployeeById()`. Your class is annotated with `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` but those are `lombok` annotations that may not be recognized by Spring. Your method `getBaseEmployeeById()` needs an explicitly defined constructor with the following signature:

```
public BaseEmployee(int id, Date birthDate, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, Date hireDate)
```

Such a constructor is currently missing.

Please add a constructor with the described signature to your class and try again.