# Hibernate force timestamp to persist/load as UTC

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, timezone, timestamp

I'm using java, mysql, hibernate (3.6.x).
On the java side I'm using java.sql.Timestamp objects.
On the mysql side I'm using datetime columns.

I want hibernate to save/load these Timestamp objects using UTC time zone regardless of system/java/mysql time zone.

I found " [How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone) " which was informative but lacking some final implementation info which I'm struggling to find.

I want to implement a UtcTimestampTypeDescriptor as shown in that thread and configure hibernate to use this instead of the normal TimestampTypeDescriptor.

How can I configure hibernate to use the UtcTimestamp type instead of the default Timestamp type?

Comment: Why don't you try implementing https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForNon-defaultTimeZone and then come up with the specific questions.

Comment: I don't want to implement a simple usertype and annotate every date/tiemstamp property. Instead I want to implement a Descriptor and register it in hibernate instead of the default timstamp descriptor. The specific question is where do I register this type with hibernate so it replaces the default one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725719/hibernate-typeresolver

Comment: I tried implementing the above link and it traces back to circa 2007 under early versions of Hibernate 3, the APIs of which have completely changed under JPA 2 and Hibnerate 4.x. There are numerous problems with the implementation that make it wholly incompatible.

Answer (score 21):

**For MySQL only**, an alternative to implementing custom Hibernate types is to add the following JDBC options to your JDBC connection URL:

```
useTimezone=true
serverTimezone=UTC
```

This will force your JDBC connection into the UTC timezone and ask MySQL to perform conversions from the JVM timezone.  The net effect is that you can keep a local timezone on your JVM (e.g. for printing out log messages and so forth), while DATETIME columns will be persisted as UTC.

For example:

```
<bean id="hibernateAnalysisSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Connection parameters -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://hostname/databaseName?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</prop>
            ...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 3):

get class `public class UtcTimestampType extends TimestampType` from [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone)
and make this code

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "yourPackage.UtcTimestampType")   
public java.util.Date date;
```

using annotations

or

```
<property name="date" column="yourColumn" type="yourPackage.UtcTimestampType" />
```

using *.hbm.xml

Comment: I don't want to annotate every date/timestamp property I have. I want hibernate to always use the UTCTimestampType instead of the default type.

Comment: It is impossible. UTCTimestampType is custom user type. If you want, you can unpack Hibernate's library and hack it.

Comment: Look under that example, at the hibernate 3.6 example. There's an example of a descriptor, not a type. Then it says that when the app starts you can register this type instead of the default one but it doesn't say how/where.. That's basically my question.

Comment: You can do this, using class Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("your.cfg.xml");  cfg.registerTypeOverride(new UtcTimestampType());

Comment: I followed your trick using annotation but hibernate seems to ignore UtcTimestampType, Why? (even debugger breakpoints not hit) I have Hibernate 3.6.10