# Hibernate using jvm time zone instead of what time zone we set

Tags: oracle, hibernate, datetime, timezone, timestamp

If server is in India - storing timestamps value in IST.
When run server from US - storing timestamps value in EST. I am using oracle database and hibernate 4.0.

Please suggest me how to get around this discrepancies.

I referred below links.

[How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java/308689#308689)

[Hibernate TypeResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725719/hibernate-typeresolver)

[How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone)

[Hibernate force timestamp to persist/load as UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823411/hibernate-force-timestamp-to-persist-load-as-utc)

[Java, Hibernate, MySQL - store UTC date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125924/java-hibernate-mysql-store-utc-date-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use "-Duser.timezone=US/Eastern" property to start server in any time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate 5.2, you can now force a custom time zone that might differ from the JVM one through the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="US/Eastern"/>
```

For more details, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/).